# How can I generate Jasper Report into XLS Format in Adempiere precisely?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, adempiere

I have set up Jasper Report to be generated into XLS format.

When I click print button, it will show like this :

[image: Printed as PDF]

Then, when I choose "Excel", download pop up will appear and my .xls format will be downloaded.

Unfortunately, when I open the file, it doesn't generated precisely, there are columns that doesn't fit correctly, like this :

[image: XLS Format in Microsoft Excel, Columns in Red box doesn't show properly]

How can I generate *JasperReports*'s report into XLS with correct format and got all my data shown correctly?

Comment: `How can I generate JasperReports's report into XLS with correct format and got all my data shown correctly?` - Your question is too broad. You should fix the report's design

Comment: The problem is nominal under Pendapatan column can't be generated into XLS format..

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same issue while creating Jasper Reports and exporting to Excel. The main reason for this is the column overlapping while creating report. If you take a closer look you will notice that any column of Jasper Report which gets overlapped turns into green from blue. If you completely remove overlapping in columns, then Excel format will come out without any issues.

**P.S ..Coming from Personal Experience!!!**

Comment: I still don't get it with the point turns into green from blue :/ can you give me screenshots?

Comment: when you click on a field or label is Jasper Report you get that selected color. I am talking about that color.

Comment: Helpful one for me

Comment: @Sajeev  glad i helped, upvote would have conveyed the same to other users. :)

Comment: @Java_BoyNextDoor Done boss

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.

How I solved it was selecting every field in the Jasper Report and setting the following properties:

**isStretchWithOverflow=**"true"

**isRemoveLineWhenBlank=**"true"

Hope it works